# RESTful API - No Inventory Issue

Tags: acumatica

Version 22 R1.  I'm seeing an Inventory Receipt entity in the Default endpoint but, not an Inventory Issue.  How can we submit an Inventory Issue to the API?  I'm trying to NOT extend the endpoint and use the API out-of-the-box.

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IN Issues weren't part of the Default endpoint in 18.200 and 20.200 versions. It is added to the Default endpoint in 22.200 version. To use the Issues page with API you will have to extend the existing endpoint in your version as the Default endpoint version 22.200 is introduced in 22R2.
[image]

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the confirmation.